# Get element by title jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I have searched but cannot find the jQuery selector that gets an element by a title. So I would be trying to get a handle on the dropdown with title =='cars'

Eg:

```
<select title='cars'>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Thanks alot,

Answer (score 99, accepted):

Use the [attribute-equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/), like this:

```
$("select[title='cars']")
```

There are other [attribute selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/) available as well if the need arises :)

Comment: Thanks Nick, sorry took so long to mark as answer, i thought it wasn't working in I.E 6 but thats because i had a console.log message throwing a javascript error! Many Thanks

Comment: One may need to check a followup question I had here...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19851247/linking-html-element-to-jquery-click-using-attribute-title

Comment: Note that the select in this code snippet is for the HTML tag select. $("[title|='cars']") gets all the elements with the title cars with any HTML tag.

Answer (score -1):

While Nick's answer solves the problem for many, it didn't for me due to a simple reason of it being case-sensitive.

Appending the attribute value with `i` would make it case-insensitive. Try this:

```
$("select[title='cars' i]")
```

This would also work in case your title is dynamic and might come with a capital case as `Cars` rather than static `cars`.

Reference for case insensitivity flag **i**: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38923109/4365626