# How to hide html elements depending on what title they have with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to hide some elements depending on their title value (it's a SharePoint site and sharePoint adds a guid to all element names and ID's), I saw that with jQuery it is possible to do this quite easily but I don't get it to work.

I saw [Get element by title jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3080339/get-element-by-title-jquery/3080346#3080346) but it doesn't work for me. A part of my code is:

```
<script src="/System%20Configuration%20Files/jquery-1.3.2.min.js";  type="text/javascript";></script>
<script src="/System%20Configuration%20Files/jquery.SPServices-0.4.1.min.js";  type="text/javascript";></script>


<script type="text/javascript">  

$("document").ready(function ($) { 

//turn off all hidden fields for different record types, then conditionally turn fields off and on based upon the item level selected
//note that field level GUIDs can change when list columns are added or amended in the list

   var control;


//Progress Status
   control = $("select[title='Progress Status']");
   control.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.style.display="none";


//Status Change Date
   control = $("select[title='Status Change Date']");

   control.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.style.display="none";



//Set for Milestone Action which is the default Item Level


//Strategic Objective
   control = $("select[title='Strategic Objective']");
   control.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.style.display="";


//Strategic Priority
   control = $("select[title='Strategic Priority']");
   control.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.style.display="";


//Performance Measure
   control = $("select[title='Performance Measure']");
   control.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.style.display="none";


//Start Date   
   control = $("select[title='Start Date']");
   control.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.style.display="";


//Target Date
   control = $("select[title='Target Date']");
   control.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.style.display="";


//Priority
   control = $("select[title='Priority']");
   control.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.style.display="";


//Percentage Complete
   control = $("select[title='% Complete']");
   control.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.style.display="";


//Baseline
   control = $("select[title='Baseline']");
   control.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.style.display="none";



//Current
   control = $("select[title='Current']");
   control.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.style.display="none";



//Target
   control = $("select[title='Target']");
   control.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.style.display="none";


      });

</script>
```

Comment: 4 spaces or a tab indent will format your code.

Comment: excuse me? Sorry I don't follow you.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery objects do not have a `parentNode` property.  That is for working with DOM elements.  jQuery can make this whole task a lot easier:

You could use [`.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get) to get the actual DOM node:

```
control.get(0).parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.style.display="none";
```

However this is kind of backwards for jQuery, what would make more sense is to use the [`.parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent) and [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css):

```
control.parent().parent().parent().css('display', 'none');
```

And even more sense would be to just look for the [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest) parent that matches what you are actually looking for.  (I.E a `<tr>`) and maybe just use [`.hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide)

```
control.closest('tr').hide();
```

As far as the selector goes, `$("select[title='Something']")` will look for a `<select title='something'>`, which may not be what you want...

Comment: Hi, I used to have getelementbyid but since sharepoint adds a guid to every id and name I want to get the element by title instead to make it a bit more maintanable.

I have a form with a few dropdownlist and textfields where the user can enter information a bout a project. Depending on what project type the choose some fields will be hidden.

So how do you suggest I change for example:
//Progress Status
   control = $("select[title='Progress Status']");
   control.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.style.display="none";

?
Thanks for your time.

Comment: Something like ``$("select[title=Progress Status]").closest('tr').hide()`... Adjust whats inside the `.closest()` for whatever element your crazy `.parentNode` chain is trying to find above the actual node...

Comment: Hi gnarf, how should I adjust what's inside the .closest() if I for example have three parentNodes?

Comment: It's not about the number of `parentNode` with `.closest()`... Read the documentation... if you are looking for the parent `tr`, use `tr` if you are looking for the closest parent `<div class='test'>` use `.closest('div.test')`

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
control.hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is probably not running because an element named "document" doesn't exist.

Change:
`$("document").ready(function ($) {`

to:

`$(document).ready(function(){`

Comment: Hi,
it was working before when I used getelementbyid but to make it a bit more maintanable (for deploying the site in several locations) I want to get the elements by title rather by id or name because sharepoint keeps changing them.

Comment: If sharepoint is adding a GUID prefix or suffix to the name, then you can still use the name as the selector.

If the GUID is a prefix, use $('select[name^=field_name]')
If the GUID is a suffix, use $('select[name$=field_name]')