# Get the next page and previous page from pagination UL

Tags: php, jquery

I have a php code 
 which generates pagination links.

I have ol > li list..

li has titles like Page 1, page 2, next page, previous page, last page, first page

I want only the links -> Previous Page and Next Page ..
So I can use jQuery and search within li

Using this, I get all the links. [Used binded click to know check if the ]

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery('#custom_pagination li').find('li').attr('title','Next Page').click(function(){alert("clicked");})
});
```

I only want 2 of them with searching the title attr.
HOw do i do it.?

tx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `.attr( attributeName, value )`, you are **setting** the atrribute on every `li`!

See: http://api.jquery.com/attr/

> .attr( attributeName, value ) attributeNameThe name of the attribute
>   to set. valueA value to set for the attribute.

You need to only select the LI's with the right title. See below:

Similar problem: [Get element by title jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3080339/get-element-by-title-jquery)

Solution:

```
$("li[title='Next Page'],li[title='Previous Page']").click(function(){alert("clicked");})
```

Updated answer:

```
$("#custom_pagination").find("a[title='Next Page'],a[title='Previous Page']").click(function(){alert("clicked");})
```