# jquery filter list with header

Tags: jquery, filter

I have some lists and some headings to the lists which I would like to filter through.
I have done that part already, as you can see in the demo link below. But I have some criteria that I can't figure out.

1. If the header match's the input by some characters, then show all the children following the `<ul>`
2. If header does NOT match the input by some characters, but some of the items in the `<ul>` does, then show the `<li>` that does, and also show the header
3. if neither the header or following `<ul>` match the input by some characters, hide both the header and items in following `<ul>`

---

```
jQuery(function() {
    var listFilter = {
        init: function(header, list) {
            $('.filterdrp_input')
            .change( function () {
                var filter = this.value.trim();

                if(filter) {                            
                    myFilter(header);
                    myFilter(list);

                    function myFilter(selector) {
                        $(selector).find('[data-name]').hide()
                        .filter('[data-name*="'+ filter +'"]')
                        .show();    
                    }
                } 
                else {
                    $(header).find("span").show();
                    $(list).find("li").show();
                }
                return false;
            })
            .keyup( function () {           
                $(this).change();
            });

        }
    }

    listFilter.init($(".list-header"), $('.filterdrp').find('ul'));

});
```

---

```
<div class="filterdrp">
<input type="text" placeholder="search" class="filterdrp_input">

<h2 class="list-header">
    <span data-name="name_01">
        name_01 
    </span>
</h2>
<ul class="list">
    <li class="list__item" data-name="item_01">
        item_01
    </li>
    <li class="list__item" data-name="item_02">
        item_02
    </li>
    <li class="list__item" data-name="item_03">
        item_03
    </li>
</ul>

<h2 class="list-header">
    <span data-name="name_02">
        name_2  
    </span>
</h2>
<ul class="list">
    <li class="list__item" data-name="item_06">
        item_06
    </li>
    <li class="list__item" data-name="item_07">
        item_07
    </li>
    <li class="list__item" data-name="item_08">
        item_08
    </li>
</ul>
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/x2oshad5/)

I have updated my solution, So here is the final working example
http://jsfiddle.net/x2oshad5/6/

Comment: This can't possibly be done without `listFilter` knowing the structure of the HTML. Since your method accepts 2 separate "lists" (wrapped as jQuery collections) it can't apply anything from one list to the next. Either change the structure of the HTML to a parent->child structure, or relax the rules so that the function knows the structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The coupling would be easier if the html structure was thus that the header was inside the same container, but as is, the best solution is to search with something like 'next()'. To prevent constant searching, you could register all headers and couple all child items, as well as the main item with it. For example:

```
var headers = $('.list-header');
headers.each(function(){
var list = $(this).next('ul.list');
this.ChildItems = $('li[data-name]', list);
this.MainItem = $('span[data-name]', this);
this.AllItems = this.MainItem.add(this.ChildItems);
```

After that, the matching should be done per header item. Several possible ways, but for an example the following works:
[(Fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/x2oshad5/1/)

```
var listFilter = {
    init: function() {
        var headers = $('.list-header');
        headers.each(function(){
            var list = $(this).next('ul.list');
            this.ChildItems = $('li[data-name]', list);
            this.MainItem = $('span[data-name]', this);
            this.AllItems = this.MainItem.add(this.ChildItems);
        });
        $('.filterdrp_input')
        .change( function () {
            var filter = this.value.trim();
            function FilterItems(items){
                return items.filter('[data-name*="'+ filter +'"]');
            }
            headers.each(function(){
                var itemstoshow = this.AllItems;
                if(filter.length > 0 && FilterItems(this.MainItem).length === 0){
                        var matches = FilterItems( this.ChildItems);
                    itemstoshow = matches.length===0 ? $() : matches.add(this.MainItem);
                }
                itemstoshow.show();
                this.AllItems.not(itemstoshow).hide();                    

            });      
            return false;
        })
        .keyup( function () {           
            $(this).change();
        });

    }
}

listFilter.init();
```

To get a case insensitive search:

```
var filter = this.value.trim().toLowerCase();
function FilterItems(items){
    return items.filter(function(){ return $(this).attr('data-name').toLowerCase().indexOf(filter) > -1;});
}
```

Although with this latter approach, you could also choose to store all data values once in initalization.

Comment: Thanks Me.Name

I can see that our approach is in the same direction. I have updated my fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/x2oshad5/2/

Comment: What about lowercase / uppercase ? It seems that neighter of ours a checking for that

Comment: JQuery's attribute contains functionality is indeed case sensitive. In the example scenario it can be easily solved with a `.toLowerCase()` on filter, which will suffice as long as all data-name attributes are added in lower case, otherwise a custom filter/regex can be used to provide case insensitive matching as can be seen here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19465157/case-insensitive-jquery-attribute-selector

Comment: could you show me, cause I can't get it to work. Thanks

Comment: Thanks a lot. I still don't get it, tried to put it in my own example, to better understand, and that didn't work.
But thanks a million.

Comment: For anyone intereseted, I have updated my code, so it works
http://jsfiddle.net/x2oshad5/6/