# Making contains selector not case sensitive

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an editor for non technical people to build their specific application. A few places though I need to insert an 'em' after the value they enter so it passes it correctly to my back-end.

For this I have something like this

```
$( "input[name*='width']" ).on( "focusout", function(){
  var value = $(this).val();
  if(value.indexOf("em") <= 0 && value.indexOf("px") <= 0 && $(this).val().length != 0){
    var newVal = value+'em';
    $(this).val(newVal).trigger('change');
  }
});
```

My question is. Is there a way to make that selector non-case sensitive so I don't have to repeat the code twice one with a lower case and one with an uppercase to catch all the cases?

To the possible duplicate. I cannot use that answer. I have already looked at that and can't use the filter in this case.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Case insensitive jQuery attribute selector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19465157/case-insensitive-jquery-attribute-selector)

Comment: @HashPsi, I have looked at that and cannot use that answer. I need to be able to use this format and not returns.

Comment: Is Question referencing selector `$( "input[name*='width']" )` ? Is there element with both `Width` , `width` values ?

Comment: Your selector is  `"input[name*='width']"` - is that the one you need to make case insensitive

Comment: PS: the <=0 means you will add emem if someone types em only

Comment: @mplungjan, they're not that technical to know what em means so the likelihood of them typing em is low to none.

Comment: But change it to <0 or ==-1 wlll handle that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I started to really think about this and came up with a different kind of solution. Since I do have multiple fields that I want this one I created an array of all said fields.

```
var valueArray = ["padding", "width", "Width", "height", "Height", "spacing", "Spacing", "size", "Size"];
```

and then used the code above to loop through the fields listed in the array. This way I don't even look at the other inputs on the screen, I don't have to worry about it being case sensitive and I don't have to repeat code.

```
for(var i = 0, ii = valueArray.length; i < ii; i++){
            $( "input[name*='"+valueArray[i]+"']" ).on( "focusout", function(){
                var value = $(this).val();
                if(value.indexOf("em") <= 0 && value.indexOf("px") <= 0 && $(this).val().length != 0){
                    var newVal = value+'em';
                    $(this).val(newVal).trigger('change');
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: Wait, so this wasnt about case sesitivity at all? It was just about 2 variations - `Width` and `width`.... you should have just gone with one of the early suggestions of `name*="idth"`. Simples!

Comment: No, I just put the most common use cases above. I didn't want to type out all the variations here. using just idth could select fields I don't want selected.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this custom expression:

```
$.expr[':'].nameCaseInsensitive = function (node, stackIndex, properties) {
    return node.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(properties[3]) > -1 ;
};
```

and use like:

```
$('input:nameCaseInsensitive("width")').on('focusout',...);
```

[**`FIDDLE DEMO`**](http://jsfiddle.net/palash/wadw0a32/)

Comment: I can't put this on all of my input fields. Only the ones that contain the word width.

Answer (score 1):

Try utilizing `.filter()` `String.prototype.match()` , with `i` flag set at `RegExp`

```
$("input").filter(function() {
  return $(this).attr("name").match(/width/i) !== null
})
```

Answer (score 1):

About the only thing you can do is select *all* `input` elements with a `name` attribute, and filter them using a case-insensitive comparison

```
$('input[name]').filter(function(){
    return $(this).attr('name').match(/width/i);
}).on('focusout',...);
```

Comment: I'm really trying to avoid this because I have some couple hundred inputs at any given time. And I need to call it several times already for different field. I don't want to make this super heavy.

Comment: I dont think you have any option. The contains selector is case sensitive.

Comment: @zazvorniki - see update - by adding `[name]` you're now only looking at input which have a name attribute - hopefully that narows it down a bit.

Comment: They all have name attributes. haha I'm thinking of maybe tiring to create an array of each field I need than then doing a loop with the contains.

Comment: How many fields are you talking about? Even with a couple of hundred fields on the page (which is a lot!) this will run quite fast indeed. Before overengineering a solution, you should check you actually have a problem.

Comment: @zazvorniki _"They all have name attributes. haha I'm thinking of maybe tiring to create an array of each field I need than then doing a loop with the contains."_ ? See _"I'm really trying to avoid this because I have some couple hundred inputs at any given time. And I need to call it several times already for different field. I don't want to make this super heavy."_ ?

Comment: @guest271314, I don't understand what you're trying to say. Looping through a couple of strings is not heavy at all.

Comment: @zazvorniki I think he was telling ME that you've already answered my question above.

Comment: @Jamiec, it's almost the weekend. That's my excuse and I'm sticking to it! :)

Comment: @zazvorniki Attempted to convey that "create an array of each field I need than then doing a loop with the contains."  could be considered "heavy" ? Where `.filter()` is single loop of input elements , even more specific with `[name]` included at selector ? _"it's almost the weekend."_ Some still do stuff at weekend same as weekday :)

Comment: @guest271314, I'm only looping through several different strings instead of every input on the screen. And with the filter I would have to repeat the code several times for each variable. I'm just trying to simplify my code a bit. I've been working three weeks straight without any weekends, so my brain is starting to shut down at the prospect of a break. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use match like this:

```
matches = value.match(/px|em/i);
if ($(this).val().length && matches !== null && matches['index'] <= 0) {
    var newVal = value+'em';
    $(this).val(newVal).trigger('change');
}
```

Comment: I'm looking at the name selector, not the px em. That's what I'm adding to the end of the input.