# Syntax error in Edge (but not in Firefox or Chrome)

Tags: jquery

I am getting the error `Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [name*="myControl" i]` error in Edge, but the page works correctly in Firefox and Chrome.

The jQuery which is causing the error is

```
function resultSelected(targetControlName, value) {
   $('[name*="' + targetControlName + '" i]').val(value);
}
```

The element which calls that function is

```
<a onclick="resultSelected('myControl','12345')" href="javascript:void(0)">12345</a>
```

I'm using jQuery 3.1.1

Comment: Edge doesn't support case-insensitive attribute selectors. Do you really need case-insensitivity?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19465157/case-insensitive-jquery-attribute-selector

Comment: Thanks @Ryan, that's good to know.  I don't absolutely need the case insensitivity, but I'd like to have it. I'll try the `filter` method of doing it.

Comment: Thanks for the link @PeterB.  I'll do it like that.