# Jquery.Match() from Input for Case Insensitive

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a search for an XML tree. This search is made through a specific node attribute. Although it already works, I want to make this search case insensitive, so it can return every single node with that attribute value.

With that in mind, I decided to make a simple function that receives an XML and the input value (texto parameter is that input). But I can't seem to make it work, I know the problem is in the match function, if I create a value like **var technician = "technician "** and put that value in the match, it works, but I want to make it dynamic, since the values should be coming from an input. How can I do it?

```
function caseinsensitve(xml, texto) {
    $(xml).find('profissao').filter(function () {
        return ($(this).attr('codigo') || '').match(/texto/i);
    });
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you use a variable in a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494035/how-do-you-use-a-variable-in-a-regular-expression)

Comment: Have you tried to convert both values to upper or lowercase while doing comparision?

Answer (score 0):

I want to thank Bojangles for giving me the idea to solve this. The answer he gave for another question is in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19465157/case-insensitive-jquery-attribute-selector/22085727).

```
 var texto = $("#pesq_profissao").val();   
 var resultado;
var valor = $(xml).find('profissao').filter(function() {
            return ($(this).attr('codigo') || '').toLowerCase().indexOf(texto.toLowerCase()) > -1;
            });

        resultado = valor;
```