# Linking html element to jQuery.click() using attribute "title"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a html code:

```
<a title="intro">INTRO?</a>
```

I need to link a jQuery click event on the  tag. Using the solution given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3080339/get-element-by-title-jquery) I wrote the following javascript:

```
jQuery("a[title='intro']").click(alert("abc"));
```

However the page is alerting ("abc") on page load rather than on clicking the  tag. Also to inform that the above code is NOT inside the load function `jQuery(function() {... }` and is a separate function.

Any solutions pls?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are invoking the `alert` function during the event registration and is passing the value returned by the `alert` as the click callback handler.

Instead you need to pass a function reference as the click callback and within the function you can add the alert call

```
jQuery("a[title='intro']").click(function(){
    alert("a")
});
```