# Select by Title JQuery

Tags: jquery, title

I don't know if my message will be clear but I paste the code here:

HTML

```
 <header>
    <h1>The Otherside</h1><br>

    <nav>
        <ul id="nav1">
            <li><a href="guitarra.jpg" title="Música">Música</a></li> 
            <li><a href="gandalf.jpg" title="Cinema">Cinema</a></li> 
            <li><a href="mon.jpg" title="Opinions">Opinions</a></li> 
            <li><a href="lleo.jpg" title="Botó 4">Botó4</a></li> 
        </ul>
    </nav>

</header>
```

I want to select the first link, by title:"Cinema". In JQuery i'm doing this but doesn't work:

```
window.jQuery("select[title='Cinema']").onclick(function (){
    alert("Works!!!);
});
```

Comment: You want to select `a` elements, yet the primary selector is `select`... ?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan It seems he thinks that `select` says "do select elements that have ..." :)

Comment: [This is a good example of why you shouldn't copy code that you don't understand...](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3080346/1947286)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get element by title jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3080339/get-element-by-title-jquery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, its `<a>` and not `<select>` and the handler is named `click` unlike it's DOM APi

```
jQuery("a[title='Cinema']").click(function (){
    alert("Works!!!);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Your selector is looking for `select` elements. Try `a` instead:

```
a[title='Cinema']
```

As Amit pointed out, you have an issue with the click handler -- it's `click()`, not `onclick()`.

See it in action after these corrections:

```js
$(function() {
  $('a[title="Cinema"]').click(function() {
    alert('You clicked "cinema".');  
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
    <h1>The Otherside</h1><br>

    <nav>
        <ul id="nav1">
            <li><a href="guitarra.jpg" title="Música">Música</a></li> 
            <li><a href="gandalf.jpg" title="Cinema">Cinema</a></li> 
            <li><a href="mon.jpg" title="Opinions">Opinions</a></li> 
            <li><a href="lleo.jpg" title="Botó 4">Botó4</a></li> 
        </ul>
    </nav>

</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is an `a` element not a `select` element.  Also `onclick` isn't a thing, but `click` is.  ALSO, you forgot to finish your string in the alert with a `'` (single-quote).

```
$("a[title='Cinema']").click(function(){
    alert('Works!!!');
});
```