# Hiding a div have a specific title in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, hidden

I need to hide a Div on  using Jquery its contain specific title  .
example in my two div have  title Stop drawing and Draw a circle

```
<div draggable="false" title="Stop drawing"  ></div>
<div draggable="false"  title="Draw a circle" ></div>
```

Please help me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get element by title jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3080339/get-element-by-title-jquery)

Comment: add ids to your divs and use `$('#id').hide();`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at **[jQuery [attribute|=value] Selector](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/sel_attribute_prefix_value.asp)** and **[jQuery Selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp)**, you can do it by following code :

```
$('div[title="Stop drawing"]').hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

Like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/n7cqbdyg/)?

```
$('div[title="Stop drawing"]').hide();
```